# Apache HTTP Server stopped working

Tags: php, apache, http, xampp

I am using xampp and when I run any .php file in my pc, the xampp give me this error and stop any page to run in my browser. When I click "**Close the program**" then page load successfully but again after 1 minute the same error appear in my screen. I install latest version of xampp 2, 3 times and I'm sure the software is also not corrupt. Anyone know the solution?

[image]

Comment: looks like you are using windows. Try re-starting your system. A typical solution for windows problems. :)

Comment: @Rajesh Yes I'm using window and just a mnt ago I restart my PC but still same error. When I minimize this error window then php file stop running in browser.

Comment: post your php code. That might have some issue.

Comment: @Rajesh no even in blank php page it show me this error. I don't think its bcuz of php code.

Comment: is this apache the one which came with xampp.??

Comment: @Rajesh yes its apache

Comment: i meant did this apache come along with xampp installation.?

Comment: @Rajesh yes this is with xampp. I have xampp 3.2.4 installed in my PC

Comment: Strange. Not sure why this is happening. May be you should un-install, restart system, then install again and check. I will try after sometime and see if I can reproduce this.

Comment: @Rajesh I did everything. Uninstall and restart. Sometimes this error appear and sometimes not

Comment: I have the same issue, After restarting the server it work fine for couple of hours but then this error reappears.