# XAMPP apache Http server has stopped working

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have tried a lot (restarting XAMPP, PC , Etc) but i cant seem to fix this:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   httpd.exe
Application Version:    2.4.17.0
Application Timestamp:  561cc534
Fault Module Name:  libapr-1.dll
Fault Module Version:   1.5.2.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 561cc6a2
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   00011fcb
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I'm on windows 7 32 Bit and MySQL starts up fine And My old version of Apache(Before I was gonna use a SQL database) Would run fine after I got this error:

I also get this in XAMPP console:

```
9:47:23 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
9:47:23 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port,  missing dependencies, 
9:47:23 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:47:23 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:47:23 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:47:23 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
9:47:23 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Have you checked that another application isn't using port 80?

Comment: I checked That and tested it under 8080 aswell(Which is what my old apache is set to)

Comment: Another application already using the same port would not cause an [ACCESS VIOLATION](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2004/06/30/170344.aspx) exception. Is there something you could add to the description, e.g. something that has changed between "it's working" and "doh"?

Comment: well all i did was download XAMPP for windows started it up and i got that

Comment: i think im having the same problem this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077247/apache-http-server-stopped-working?rq=1

Answer (score 14):

**To fix this problem:**

1 - stop  apache web server from xampp  panel

2 - choose (httpd.conf) from config menu on xampp panel

3 -insert  code to the end of file

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
  ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

Comment: saves my lots of time buddy, thanks a lot. may I know the reason of it please ?

Comment: Beautiful! Worked for me on Windows 2012 Server.

Answer (score -1):

Comment out the line
`'error_log="C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log"'`
in **php.ini**

Comment: Can you provide more information on why this setting should be commented out? or how/why it would apply to his problem.

Comment: I believe, if the logs folder doesn't exit, the XAMPP crashes. Manually creating logs folder under C:\xampp\php seems to have solved the problem.